# Replace names with another form of spelling - Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

How do I replace product names such as

```
PEACOAT-01
GREGORY-01
MINESWEEP-01
2012BLEU-04
```

to

```
PEA COAT 01 
GREGORY 01 
MINE SWEEP 01 
2012 BLEU 04
```

The file I download from the backend differs from the format we use internally and I want to figure out if there is a way to format all at once.

I am currently using

> =SUBSTITUTE(A2,"-"," ")

to rid of the "-", but it does not make all the spacing between the words.

Comment: How is Excel suppose to know where one word ends and another begins?

Comment: @nananaing, you have no fixed pattern like for `PEACOAT-01` you want `Pea Coat 01` but `GREGORY-01` you want `GREGORY 01`!!

Answer (score 0):

If the list of names is finite, create a table where you map the system name with the preferred version of the name. Then you can use a lookup formula or Power Query to show the preferred name.